# How to set X-Axis values as dates in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, datetime, plot, time-series

I am generating a plot from a ML model which is predicting stock prices from yahoo finance.

The plot consists of `actual_prices` + `predicted_prices`.

I want to change the x axis values to my test data time range, but this removes the plots completely when I try to set an `xlim`.

I want these same plots but with the 0-500 x axis values changed to the `test_start` and `test_end` datetime values like the 2nd picture:

[image]

When I include `plt.gca().set_xlim(test_start, test_end)`', the plots disappear:

[image]

**Relevant code for:**

- Loading test data

```
test_start = dt.datetime(2020, 9, 19)
test_end = dt.datetime.now()

test_data = web.DataReader(company, 'yahoo', test_start, test_end)
actual_prices = test_data['Close'].values
```

- Plot

```
plt.plot(actual_prices, color='black', label=f"Actual {company} Price")
plt.plot(predicted_prices, color='green', label=f"Predicted {company} Price")
plt.title(f'Predicted {company} Share Price for tomorrow: {prediction}')
    #plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=500))
#plt.gca().set_xlim(time_start, time_end)
plt.xlabel(f'Data shown from {time_start} until {time_end}')
plt.ylabel(f'{company} Share Price')
plt.legend()
        
plt.show()
```

I think it may be because the dates `time_start` and `time_end` do not exist within the `predicted_prices` `np.array` and therefore cannot be plotted against? If so, how can I plot the dates against `actual_prices` whilst still including the `predicted_prices` line?

Answer (score 0):

You need to submit the indices themselves, i.e. Date and then the price data. Below I give an example with two lines, the data has different lengths, I took the data through the slice and placed it for drawing. If there is no Date data for predicted prices, then you need to create one and put it in ax.plot.

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

test_data = web.DataReader('F', 'yahoo', start='2018-08-31', end='2018-10-31')
print(test_data)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(test_data.index[15:], test_data['Close'][15:])
ax.plot(test_data.index[:20], test_data['Close'][:20])
fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

**Update**

```
test_data = web.DataReader('F', 'yahoo', start='2018-08-31', end='2018-10-31')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(test_data.index, test_data['Close'])
ax.plot(test_data.index[15:35], test_data['Close'][:20])
fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I thought it may be worth mentioning that actual_prices is a list, where as predicted_prices is a np array, meaning .index returns an attribute error. Should I still add a date column to predicted_prices or should I convert it to a list to use ax.plot?

Comment: Hi! In this case, I used indexes. These may not necessarily be indexes, it is enough to put a list with dates or datetime. The data should be on what date you are making a prediction (this is the x-axis), and the values themselves are the y-axis and there should be the same number of them. Understand?

Comment: @AliBaba44 all okey?

Comment: No sorry cannot get it to work (student programmer), putting on hold for now. It is ok for you to close this ticket

Comment: There's nothing complicated: just take through the slice a certain amount of the date-time array and the same number of predicted ones.

Comment: Updated the code: took date time from 15 to 34 indices, and values from 0 to 19.